# I initialized a variable inside of a constructor, but it's still null when I try to use it in another method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bukkit

So here is the constructor

```
private ActionbarTitleObject timer = TitleFactory.newBarTitle("");
private Plugin plugin;
HashMap<String, Parkour> parkours = null;

public MineJump() {}

public MineJump(ArrayList<Player> players, String configPath, Plugin plugin)
{
    super(players);
    this.plugin = plugin;
    parkours = Parkour.load(configPath, players);
    System.out.println(parkours.get("p1").getCurrentSpawn()); //here I get the right value
}
```

but when i try to use the parkours hash map in this Method

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e)
{
    System.out.println(parkours.get("p1").getCurrentSpawn()); //parkours is null here :(
}
```

I get a NullPointerException. Why is that?

I used the non-argument constructor to only to this: `Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MineJump(), this);`

Could that have caused the error? If yes, it would be nice if you could explain to me why. :)

Comment: Could you provide more information about when and how you instantiate `parkours` ?

Comment: Did you use the no-argument-constructor? this would explain your null pointer.

Comment: Use a debugger. And check if you swallow exceptions silently somewhere.

Comment: @MickaëlB yes, just give me a second.

Comment: @wtfzn yes I did use the no-argument-constructor to do this:
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MineJump(), this); but that's it.

Comment: @freggy you aren't initializing the `parkours` variable inside of your default constructor, so if you try and use that method after initializing as you just described then you will get a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained, you used your no argument constructor. This constructor does not set `parkours` to a different value than null.

You need to use your second constructor with arguments like this:

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MineJump(players, configPath, plugin), this);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation is that `onPlayerMove` is called as a side effect result when calling the `super`() in the constructor